# Add/Append a new key-value pair in JSON after reading from another JSON file in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I have two JSON files with a bunch of configurations. When new custom configurations are added in `globalconfigs.json`, I want to add those key value pairs in another `app1configs.json`. Let me explain it a bit.

`globalconfigs.json:`

```
{
    "App1": {
       "files": [
         "app1configs.json"
       ],
       "values": {
         "NewConfigsBool": true,
         "NewConfigsValues": {
             "App1SampleConfigs": "CustomConfig1"
         },
         "CustomSQLFiles": true,
         "SQLPaths": [
              "D:\\some\\location\\to\\myconfigs.sql"
        ]
            }
        }
```

The above json code is a little snippet of the `globalconfigurations.json`. If the `"NewConfigsBool":`is true, I want to copy the key value pairs in `"NewConfigsValues"` to another JSON file which looks like this. `App1` is one of many, however they all follow the same syntax. And each app has its own `appconfigs.json`.

`app1configs.json`:

```
{
    "globalsettings": {
        "values": {
            "sqlstring": "alkjsdaklsjdklajsd3910840294",
            "hostname": "somesite.local",
            "filepath": "D:\\dummy\\location"
        }
    },
       "files": [
            "mysettings.json",
            "executors.dll",
            "logrecords.txt"
        ]
}
```

The above code is how `app1configs.json` normally looks. However, once `"NewConfigsBool"` is true, `app1configs.json` should look like this:

```
{
    "globalsettings": {
        "values": {
            "sqlstring": "alkjsdaklsjdklajsd3910840294",
            "hostname": "somesite.local",
            "filepath": "D:\\dummy\\location",
            "App1SampleConfigs": "CustomConfig1"
        }
    },
    "files": [
        "mysettings.json",
        "executors.dll",
        "logrecords.txt"
    ],
    "SQLPaths": [
        "D:\\some\\location\\to\\myconfigs.sql"
    ]
}
```

These custom configurations are not always going to have the same "keys". The user enters the key and the value so it can change. I'd like to highlight the changes here too. Basically, the configurations in `NewConfigsValues` in `globalconfigs.json` are stored in `globalsettings` in `app1configs.json`. And the `SQLPaths` are stored as well like I have shown above.

I thought I could do text replacement here however, since the keys are not the same, I wasn't able to do text replacement.

I would very much appreciate help here or any kind of feedback.

Comment: But if the user types in the keys and values, how can we be certain the `appXXconfigs.json` files will always have `globalsettings` ?

Comment: `globalsettings` prior to the user adding in the keys and values are going to stay the same. The new keys and values are just added on to them. But I get your point. Maybe adding them in somewhere other than `globalsettings` would be a better or safer option?

Comment: Where are `NewConfigsBool` and `NewConfigsValues` in your example files ?

Comment: @filimonic Please see my edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution Example:

It reads `globalconfigs.json`, loops through each application, checks if `NewConfigsBool` is true or false.

If `NewConfigsBool` is true, it loops through all application `.files` and adds or upodates `%file%.globalsettings.values.%parameterName%`.

The part for SQL is not implemented so it's similar and it's for you

```
$root = 'S:\SCRIPTS\GC'
$backupNameFormat = '{0}.b{1}.bak'

$pathGS = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($root,'globalconfigs.json')


$GSData = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($pathGS) | ConvertFrom-Json 

$applicationNames = @($GSData | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name'  ) 
$applicationDataList = $applicationNames |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $_
            Data = $GSData.($_)
        }
    }

forEach ($ad in $applicationDataList) {
    if (($null -ne $ad.Data) -and ($null -ne $ad.Data.values) -and ($ad.Data.values.NewConfigsBool -eq $true)) {
        $files = @($ad.Data.files)
        if ($files.Count -le 0) {
            Write-Warning "For application $($ad.Name) new config is requested, but no files to patch"
        } else {
            foreach ($fName in $files) {
                $fPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($root, $fName)
                if (-not [System.IO.File]::Exists($fPath)) {
                    Write-Warning "For application $($ad.Name) new config is requested, but no file $($fPath) can not be found"
                } else {
                    $fData = $null
                    try {
                        $fData = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($fPath) | ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction Stop
                    } catch {
                        Write-Warning "For application $($ad.Name) new config is requested, but file $($fPath) can not be read: $($_.Exception.Message)"
                    }
                    if (($null -ne $fData) -and ($null -ne $fData.globalsettings) -and ($null -ne $fData.globalsettings.values)) {
                        if ($null -ne $ad.Data.values.NewConfigsValues) {
                            $newValues = $ad.Data.values.NewConfigsValues
                            $newValueNames = @($newValues | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name')
                            $hasErrors = $false
                            try {
                                $newValueNames | 
                                    % {Add-Member -InputObject $fData.globalsettings.values -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_ -Value ($newValues.($_)) -Force -ErrorAction Stop}
                            } catch {
                                $hasErrors = $true
                                Write-Warning  "For application $($ad.Name) new config application failed for file $($fPath): $($_.Exception.Message)"
                            }

                            if ($hasErrors -eq $false) {
                                $backupName = [String]::Format($backupNameFormat, [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($fPath), [DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString('yyyy_MM_dd.HH_mm_ss'))
                                $backupPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($root,$backupName)
                                $backupComplete = $false
                                try {
                                    [System.IO.File]::Copy($fPath, $backupPath, $false)
                                    $backupComplete = $true
                                } catch {
                                    Write-Warning "Unable to backup file $($fPath) to $($backupPath): $($_.Exception.Message)"
                                    $backupComplete = $false
                                }
                                if ($backupComplete -eq $true) {
                                    try {
                                        $fData | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Out-File -FilePath $fPath -Force -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction Stop
                                    } catch {
                                        Write-Warning -Message "Unable to save file $($fPath): $($_.Exception.Message)"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            Write-Warning -Message "For application $($ad.Name) new config is requested, but file $($fPath) can not be patched because `"NewConfigsValues`" is empty"
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        Write-Verbose "Ignoring application $($ad.Name) configuration because it's `"values.NewConfigsBool`" NE True"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much. I think I can take out the error messages and reduce the total lines too. And yes, I should be able to do it for `SQLPaths` too. This script is a little bit complex for me to understand but I'll take my time doing it for sure. Thank you very much once again.